# Inserting millions of records in table

Tags: java, database

what is the best way to insert millions of records into table.

Some approaches are:

1) writing jdbc program to insert data.

2) writing pl/sql procedure to insert data.

can any one please suggest other approaches and best as well.

Comment: It depends. How is the data stored now or is it generated on the fly?

Comment: This depends entirely on the sort of data (size of data/rows), and of course entirely on the database system you are using.  Each has their own way of bulk-loading data.

Comment: What is the data source, where do you take it from?

Comment: Values are generated on the fly

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you should use the Data Migration tool that comes with most of the databases like MS Sql Server.

Otherwise JDBC/PL-SQL will behave same, But Its better to run all the queries in a Transaction and PL-SQL will have a bit better hand on managing Transaction.

But In Java you can read the source a bit efficiently then PL-SQL (if it is possible) like if you have a source of XML, CSV file etc.

Comment: Random Values gather from where...?

Comment: generated using rand function

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a [batch insert](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/Jdbc-batch-insert.shtml) in JDBC (if your JDBC driver is 2.0 and higher).

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is mysql:

```
INSERT INTO x (a,b)
VALUES 
 ('1', 'one'),
 ('2', 'two'),
 ('3', 'three')
```

If it is one time only issue, I dont think java should be involoved.

**I suggest you tell us where do you take your data from?**

Comment: Then who will write one million line of Values :) U need java here :p

Comment: Since there is no details, I assume it is a csv file or something so you can convert it with some tool.. but you got a point... (-:

Comment: i tried same, but it is not working on oracle, giving syntax error

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL procedure will let you handle transactions effectively. It also depends on where are you going to read the data from? Not that PLSQL can't do some stuff but Java might be better at it.

Answer (score 0):

Batch processing with JDBC API will do the job for such huge no of records.